# how to filter databse from mongodb between to string formatted date

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
[
   { "item": "journal", "qty": 25,"date":"1/1/2016", "status": "A" },
   { "item": "notebook", "qty": 50,"date":"10/1/2016", "status": "A" },
   { "item": "paper", "qty": 100,"date":"20/1/2016", "status": "D" },
   { "item": "planner", "qty": 75,"date":"1/2/2016", "status": "D" },
   { "item": "postcard", "qty": 45,"date":"10/2/2016", "status": "A" },
   { "item": "postcard", "qty": 45,"date":"20/5/2016", "status": "A" },
   { "item": "postcard", "qty": 45,"date":"30/7/2016", "status": "A" },
   { "item": "postcard", "qty": 45,"date":"2/3/2017", "status": "A" },
   { "item": "postcard", "qty": 45,"date":"5/5/2017", "status": "A" },
   { "item": "postcard", "qty": 45,"date":"6/5/2017", "status": "A" },
   { "item": "postcard", "qty": 45,"date":"8/10/2017", "status": "A" },
   { "item": "postcard", "qty": 45,"date":"11/10/2017", "status": "A" },
   { "item": "postcard", "qty": 45,"date":"12/11/2017", "status": "A" },
   { "item": "postcard", "qty": 45,"date":"4/3/2018", "status": "A" },
   { "item": "postcard", "qty": 45,"date":"5/6/2018", "status": "A" },
   { "item": "postcard", "qty": 45,"date":"6/7/2018", "status": "A" },
   { "item": "postcard", "qty": 45,"date":"7/7/2018", "status": "A" },
   { "item": "postcard", "qty": 45,"date":"17/11/2018", "status": "A" },
   { "item": "postcard", "qty": 45,"date":"19/12/2018", "status": "A" },
   { "item": "postcard", "qty": 45,"date":"5/1/2019", "status": "A" },
   { "item": "postcard", "qty": 45,"date":"7/1/2019", "status": "A" },
   { "item": "postcard", "qty": 45,"date":"14/3/2019", "status": "A" }
]
```

Above Is my database structure.

```
db.lichi.find({date: {$gte : '1/1/2016', $lt : '1/1/2019'}})
```

Here is the query i am trying to fetch data from database.

Here in database i have string formatted date.
I am tring to fetch using above way that, didn't work.

gave result

```
  { "item": "journal", "qty": 25,"date":"1/1/2016", "status": "A" },
  { "item": "notebook", "qty": 50,"date":"10/1/2016", "status": "A" }
```

Only two documents.

PLease have a look.

Comment: Use momentjs to format the date first

Comment: I am using python

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/js.momentjs/

Comment: Could you please help me how to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing dates as string is not the best idea since in case like this you have to compare strings instead of dates. If for some reason you have to keep `date` as string then you can convert it in your query using [$dateFromString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/) and then apply your filtering condition:

```
db.lichi.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            date: {
                $dateFromString: {
                    dateString: "$date",
                    format: "%d/%m/%Y"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            date: { $gte: ISODate("2016-01-01T00:00:00Z"), $lt: ISODate("2019-01-01T00:00:00Z") }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: how i can format if i i have date of two digit format like "01/02/2016" in database

Comment: @soubhagya take a look here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/#format-specifiers